# Pasar variable jquery a otra función

Tags: jquery

Hola estoy intentando pasar una variable de una función a otra para poder hacer uso de ella.

Esta es la primera función donde obtengo `envio` a través de keyup y lo quiero mandar a la siguiente función.

```
$('body').on( 'keyup','.inputcalculo', function(e) {
        var fila = $(this).parents('tr');
        var cantidad = $(fila).find('.cntComprada').val();
        if(cantidad == 'undefined'){
          cantidad = 0;
        }
        var precio = $(fila).find('.ePrecioUnid').val();
        if(precio == 'undefined'){
          precio = 0;
        }
        
        var envio = $('#elEnvio').val()
        if(envio == 'undefined'){
        envio = 0;
        return envio;
        }

        fila.find('.eSubTotal').val(Math.round(cantidad * precio * 100) / 100);
        actualizarTotales();
    });
```

Esta es la siguiente función pero me devuelve todo el rato `undefined`:

```
function actualizarTotales(envio){
        var tabla = $('#tabla');
        var subtotal = 0;
        var iva = 0;
        var total = 0;
        $(tabla).find('.eSubTotal').each(function(index, value){
          var valor = $(value).val();
          if( !isNaN(parseFloat(valor))){ // NaN = Not a number
            subtotal += parseFloat(valor);
          }
        });
        
        console.log(envio);
        iva = subtotal * 21 / 100;
        total = subtotal + iva;
        $('#subtotal').val(Math.round(subtotal * 100) / 100);
        $('#iva').val(Math.round(iva * 100) / 100);
        $('#total').val(Math.round(total * 100) / 100);
    }
```

Comment: No la estás pasando: `actualizarTotales();` debería ser `actualizarTotales(envio);`.

Comment: Es cierto! muchas gracias @PabloLozano , crea una respuesta si quieres con la solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras una función, por ejemplo

```
function actualizarTotales(envio){ ...}
```

El parámetro es una una variable que sólo existe dentro de la función. El que tengas una variable global que se llame igual (en este caso `envio`) no significa que automáticamente se le esté pasando. De hecho, está evitando que se pueda acceder a ella:

Por tanto tienes dos soluciones:

- eliminar el parámetro
- pasar la variable como parámetro

```js
const texto ="Hola";

function escribeEnMayusculas(texto) {
  //texto "esconde" a la constante global texto
  console.log(texto.toUpperCase());
}

function escribeEnMayusculasTexto() {
  console.log(texto.toUpperCase());
}

escribeEnMayusculas(texto); //podemos pasar la variable global
escribeEnMayusculas("otro Texto"); //o podemos pasar otra cosa
escribeEnMayusculasTexto(); //aquí sólo existe la variable global
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @PabloLozano funciono perfectamente!

Comment: Que tan recomendable es pasar variables globales? O hay formas para eso, por ejemplo el uso de ajax y obtener los datos o simplemente en este caso crear una variable global para pasarlo a una funcion

Comment: Depende de qué entendamos por global y el uso que tenga esa función. No hay una respuesta absoluta